# How to delete GAVs in Nexus 3 through Nexus REST API

Tags: nexus

Is there a way to delete GAVs through a REST API in Nexus 3?  From various
google searches it appears that this capability existed in Nexus 2, but not in
Nexus 3 yet.  **Is that true?**

I tried the following with my current Nexus installation, which is OSS 3.2.1-01:

I was trying to delete GAV:

```
groupId = org.mycompany.myproject
artifactId = myartifact
version = 1.0.0

$ curl --request DELETE --user "USERNAME:PASSWORD" --write-out '%{http_code}\n' http://my-server:8081/service/local/repositories/my-repo/content/org.mycompany.myproject/myartifact/1.0.0
```

This gave me a 405.

I also looked at the release notes for 3.3 through 3.5 and nothing jumped out
that REST API support was added.

I also looked into
https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/REST+and+Integration+API.  I downloaded
the nexus-book-examples and downloaded several of the Javadocs (nexus-core,
nexus-repository, nexus-common, nexus-script, nexus-commands, nexus-selector)
for version 3.2.1-01 and started to look through the code.  It was not clear
where to start with a simple program to delete GAVs.

Am I correct that you cannot delete GAVs through the REST API in Nexus 3?  Is
there a plan to support this in a future Nexus 3 release?  Is there a way to do
what I want to do by creating a Groovy script using the code referenced by the
REST+and+Integration+API link above?  Is there some sample code which will help
bootstrap me to using the above code (either 3.2.1-01, or a newer version of
Nexus).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at our Beta REST API in Nexus Repository 3. Upgrade to a version greater than 3.3, preferably to 3.5 (just so you are using latest and greatest) and navigate to:

http://nexushostname:nexusport/swagger-ui/

Since the REST API is currently Beta we have yet to publish documentation or fanfare around it while we let people experiment with it and give us feedback.

You should see endpoints for deleting components and assets. You will likely want to use the component delete, so that it will clean up all associated assets.

Let me know your mileage!

Comment: Thanks.  I will install a test Nexus 3.5 when I have some time and play with it.  Sorry I didn't respond earlier.  I expected to see an email notification that my post had been answered, but I didn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you can delete an ASSET (individual file) or a COMPONENT (a set of files, like jar+md5+sha1+pom.xml representing an artifact) only if you know the assetId or the componentId

https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/components-api

https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/assets-api

So you should issue a separate search call passing the GAV and finding out the componentId, then use the componentId to delete in a second call.

However I see here https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-11266  and here

https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-11881 that people can delete an asset just by specifying the entire path... I have tried with

curl -u admin:admin123 -X "DELETE" -w "%{http_code}" http://localhost:8081/repository/deployments/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.18/commons-compress-1.18.jar

and it gives me a HTTP 204 (no content). In my case "deployments" is a hosted repository. I have tried the same command on "central" (aproxy repo) and I get a 405.

But if I try to download the whole component (including pom, sha1 etc) with

curl -u admin:admin123 -X "DELETE" -w "%{http_code}" http://localhost:8081/repository/deployments/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.18/

I get a HTTP 404.

I know, it's painful and in Nexus2 it was much easier.